# How to access knockout observables from different object scopes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

My data model is consisting of two objects; project and task.
I load my data from the db via json and MVC-services and map my observableArrays like this:

```
viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    // some code...

    // projects
    self.Projects = ko.observableArray();
    var mappedProjects = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: "myService/GetProjectsByUserId",
        data: "userID=" + meID,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (allData) {
            mappedProjects = $.map(allData, function (item) {
                return new Project(item);
            });
        }
    });
    self.Projects(mappedProjects);

    // tasks
    self.Tasks = ko.observableArray();
    var mappedTasks = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: "myService/GetTasksByUserID",
        data: "userid=" + meID,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (allData) {
            mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function (item) {
                return new Task(item, self.Projects);    // is there a smarter way to access self.Projects from the Scene prototype?
                //return new Task(item);
            });
        }
    });
    self.Tasks(mappedTasks);


    //some more code...

};
```

where

```
Project = function (data) {
    this.projectID = data.projectID;
    this.type = ko.observable(data.type);
};


Task = function (data, projects) {

    this.taskID = data.taskID;
    this.projectID = data.projectID;

    //this.projecttype = ??? simpler solution?

    this.projecttype = ko.computed(function () {   // Is there a simpler way to access 'viewModel.Projects' from within 'Task'?
        var project = ko.utils.arrayFirst(projects, function (p) {
            return p.projectID === self.projectID;
        });
        if (!project) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return project.headerType();
        }
    });

};
```

The thing is (as you see) I want to access the projectType inside the Task-object. Is there a simpler way to do this than instantiating the object with the self.Projects as input?

Could self.Projects be bound when defined in some way so I could access it via the DOM?

Comment: yes ! you can if you have all your functions declared in `viewModel` function , then `self.Projects` becomes globally available to internal functions i.e `Task` .

Comment: a somewhat bigger problem I see is that you are initializing self.projects immediately after the ajax call; since it's async, self.Projects will never get set with the actual mapped data, but rather the empty array

Comment: How do I access the viewModel  from Task = function(data){}?

The viewModel isn´t bound when I access the data, will that not cause problems?

Comment: @dperry async is false. probably not the most clever way to do it, but it works.

Comment: it's going to lock your app. you should move self.Projects(mappedProjects); immediately after the mapping call inside the success function

Comment: @AsleG your should use ajax callback functions(success,complete) to load data into observableArray .

Comment: Wouldn´t self.Project then we local to the success-callback?

Comment: @AsleG as on top you refered self=this you can use `self` inside sub function like this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/26921/

Comment: @supercool thanks, would you mind showing me how?

Comment: no, it's scoped to `self`, which is declared outside the success function, same as the array

Comment: @supercool, you didn't actually move the statement into the success function in your fiddle

Comment: yes @dperry i just focused showing  `self.projects` accessible inside Task function tough it's obvious  .

Comment: @AsleG here's an update to supercool's fiddle, moving the project and task initialization to the success function, and not using async:false http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26923/

Comment: @supercool In my project I use the Task and the Project object with several viewmodels. Thus making Task and Project sub functions of each is a lot of work. Is there another way around this?

Comment: you could wrap the various viewmodels with an "app viewmodel", and move the definition of Task and Project to that level. then each child viewmodel would share access to the common objects. be sure you bind your view to the main viewmodel, instead

Comment: Thanks @dperry. I´m not sure I totally follow you. Could you show that in your fiddle, please?

Comment: not really, since there's only one viewmodel defined there

Comment: In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26924/ I have added a viewModel2 (similar to viewModel in the example above and placed the sub function outside the viewModel. How should the app viewModel be defined with Task and Project now?

Comment: I started wiring them together with a parent viewmodel, and I'm noticing that the code you have for each is duplicated and seems fairly specific to that instance. would it make more sense to just bind your various views to the same viewmodel?

Comment: here's a fiddle showing the parent/child viewmodel approach: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26925/  the issue here is that since Project and Task have been defined inside appVM, the constructors aren't available outside that viewmodel. you'd have to rewrite/restructure to allow each to be "public" objects while allowing one to reference the contents of the other

Comment: Thanks @dperry. I might need to look at a different approach I think. Rewriting would be massive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it looks like that you have multiple view models dependent on `Task` and `Project` objects. For decoupling between components, i would say to use [ko.postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) plugin. You can easily have synchronization between viewmodels and non-knockout components using `publishOn` and `subscribeTo` extensions.

So your `Task` object will subscribe to `Projects` `observableArray` in viewModel like

```
Task = function (data) {

    this.taskID = data.taskID;
    this.projectID = data.projectID;
    var projects = ko.observableArray().subscribeTo("projectsLoaded",true);

    //this.projecttype = ??? simpler solution?

    this.projecttype = ko.computed(function () {   // Is there a simpler way to access 'viewModel.Projects' from within 'Task'?
        var project = ko.utils.arrayFirst(projects(), function (p) {
            return p.projectID === self.projectID;
        });
        if (!project) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return project.headerType();
        }
    });

};
```

and in your viewModel, you just have to make Projects observable array publish "projectsLoaded" topic/event. Like

```
viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    // some code...
    // projects
    self.Projects = ko.observableArray().publishOn("projectsLoaded");
    // ....
}
```

Whenever the `projects` array changes in viewModel, you will always have the latest value in Task `project` array.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/wffug341/3/

Comment: Thank a lot! This was helpful Am using the ko.postbox, @Dandy. I´building a SPA with several "pages" og viewmodels and some of them are reusing both "Projects" and "Tasks". Often I choose the syncWith()-option. But I struggle with recursion when coupling my data-objects (as when adding tasks as an observableArray on the Project-object). Would really like to see a tutorial/best practice on how to do this structure.

Comment: would you know if I can use "subscribeTo("projectsLoaded")" if the source data is shared with syncWith("projectsLoaded")?

Comment: @Asle, Yes, you can subscribe to that.

Comment: While I am using pubsub-js in place of knockout-postbox, I started getting no function as publishOn, What do you recommend to use in place of publichOn method in case I am using pubsub-js with knockout-js?